# Maximo MAXINTMSGTRK table: How to extract text from MSGDATA column? (HUGEBLOB)

Tags: oracle, blob, message-queue, text-extraction, maximo

I'm attempting to extract the text from the MSGDATA column (HUGEBLOB) in the MAXINTMSGTRK table:

[image]

I've tried the options outlined here: [How to query hugeblob data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50073629/how-to-query-hugeblob-data):

```
select
    msg.*,
    utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(msgdata,1000,1)) msgdata_expanded,
    dbms_lob.substr(msgdata, 1000,1) msgdata_expanded_2
from
    maxintmsgtrk msg
where
    rownum = 1
```

However, the output is not text:

[image]

**How can I extract text from MSGDATA column?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's is possible to do it using Automation script, uncompress data using psdi.iface.jms.MessageUtil class.

```
from psdi.iface.jms import MessageUtil
...
msgdata_blob = maxintmsgtrkMbo.getBytes("msgdata")
byteArray = MessageUtil.uncompressMessage(msgdata_blob, maxintmsgtrkMbo.getLong("msglength"))

msgdata_clob = ""
for symb1 in byteArray:
    msgdata_clob = msgdata_clob + chr(symb1)
```

Comment: I found another way to convert Byte Array to String. It's more simple:  

`from java.lang import String  
strData = String(byteArray)  
`

Comment: You can create a new custom table "ZZmaxintmsgtr" with MSGDATA_CLOB column.
Create a new relationship 1 to 1 from "maxintmsgtrk" table to "ZZmaxintmsgtrk" table (using unique id column value).
Use Escalation or Cron task + Automation script to uncompress data from "maxintmsgtrk.MSGDATA" and put uncompressed data into "ZZmaxintmsgtrk.MSGDATA_CLOB".
As result, you can use SQL query against "ZZmaxintmsgtrk.MSGDATA_CLOB".

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like it's **not possible** because the value is compressed:

> Starting in Maximo 7.6, the messages written by the Message Tracking
>   application are stored in the database. They are no longer written as
>   xml files as in previous versions.
>
> Customers have asked how to search and view MSGDATA data from the
>   MAXINTMSGTRK table.
>
> It is not possible to search or retrieve the data in the maxintmsgtrk
>   table in 7.6.using SQL. The BLOB field is stored compressed.

[MIF 7.6 Message tracking changes](https://render-prd-trops.events.ibm.com/support/pages/mif-76-message-tracking-changes)